# How can we achieve multi-tenant option in the Spring scheduler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

we have implemented multi-tenant option in our application. Each tenant have each separate DB. using application filter i can manage or assign the each tenant from the request. same how can we do it in the spring boot scheduler?

```
@component     
public class scheduler{
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
        public void reminderEmail() {
    //how can we fetch the exact data from exact tenant DB?
    //since there is no request how can we get the tenant name for 
     fetching exact tenant db?    
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can we achieve this?

Comment: if each tenant has a separate DB, can't you have a table in the DB that says what you need per tenant? (nitpick:you have a typo in your question title. )

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
...
public class TenantContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenantId(String tenantId) {     
        CONTEXT.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static String getTenantId() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }
...
}
```

then your Filter or Spring MVC interceptor could do this just before chaining the request:

```
String tenantId = request.getHeader(TENANT_HEADER_NAME);
TenantContext.setTenantId(tenantId);
```

and reset it on the way back:

```
TenantContext.setTenantId(null);
```

To use it in a thread not related to an http request you could just do:

```
TenantContext.setTenantId("tenant_1");
```

More could be found in my blog post [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html)

Comment: Thanks ootero, this how we were implemented.   how to achieve with in the scheduler method.

Comment: It depends what you would like to do in the scheduled task, process one or all tenants? If you would like to process one tenant, do you know which tenant?

Comment: @Ramesh S did you find any solution?

Comment: Make sure to clean the threadlocal once the job is complete or you might leak the threadlocal and the data it references

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multitenant setup similar to the one at this link: https://www.ricston.com/blog/multitenancy-jpa-spring-hibernate-part-1/ and/or you have a default tenant. The easiest way to accomplish this is to add a static method to your CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl class that changes the default tenant for asynchronous tasks that have no session. This is because that the scheduled task will always use the default tenant.

**CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.java**

```
private static String DEFAULT_TENANTID = "tenantId1";

public static void setDefaultTenantForScheduledTasks(String tenant) {
    DEFAULT_TENANT = tenant;
}
```

**ScheduledTask.java**

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=20000)
public void runTasks() { 

    CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.setDefaultTenantForScheduledTasks("tenantId2");
    //do something
    CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.setDefaultTenantForScheduledTasks("tenantId1");

}
```

Then after the scheduled task is complete change it back. That is how we accomplished it and it works for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a request to determine which tenant is currently active and using tenant to determine database connections, then it's impossible to do anything involving the database from a scheduled task since the scheduled task has no tenant id